# Error running sqlx migrate run: "migration was previously applied but is missing in the resolved migrations"

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web, rust-sqlx

I'm working on setting up database migrations using `sqlx` , `actix-web` , `postgresql` for my Rust project. I've added a new migration with the following steps, but I'm encountering an error when attempting to run the migrations.

1-I added a new migration with the following command:

> sqlx migrate add -r subscribe

This command created two files:

- 20231106184526_subscribe.down.sql
- 20231106184526_subscribe.up.sql

2-I then checked the migration info using:

> sqlx migrate info

It listed the migration as pending:

> 20231106184526/pending subscribe

3 - Finally, I attempted to run the migration with:

> sqlx migrate run

However, this resulted in the following error:

> error: migration 20231103093446 was previously applied but is missing in the resolved migrations

I have not removed any migration files manually, and I'm unsure why sqlx is unable to find the 20231103093446 migration, as it was applied successfully before.

What does this error mean in the context of sqlx migrations? How can I resolve this error and successfully run my migrations?